# Sending a response (using a callback?) after a forEach iterates over an array

Tags: javascript

I'm saving to the database multiple times, then I want to res.send(people.json). I tried "then" and I tried "call". I'm not sure if I'm doing this right... because it keeps breaking the app. How do I make something happen after forEach iterates completely?

```
people.forEach(saveRequest).call(res.json(people)); //   TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

people.forEach(saveRequest).then(res.json(people)); //   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: what is your requirement.

Comment: Presumably, we are talking about [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).  If so: `people.forEach(saveRequest);res.json(people);`

Comment: will that wait for foreach to finish? Thank you

Comment: You have not provided code for `saveRequest`. So, we do not know if that is synchronous, or asynchronous. Thus, we don't know if all of the calls to `saveRequest` will have completed. They will have returned, but if there is an asynchronous operation, all of them will, probably, not have completed (just all of them would have started).

Comment: [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach) returns *undefined* so you can't chain it like that.

Comment: You need to follow up on the comments and answer the questions posed there, mainly whether `saveRequest` is asynchronous or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, we are talking about [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).  If so then the following will execute `res.json(people)` after `people.forEach(saveRequest);` completes:

```
people.forEach(saveRequest);
res.json(people);
```

`Array.prototype.forEach()` is synchronous, but the function `saveRequest` may, or may not, be synchronous.  With the information you have provided in the question, there is no way for us to know. If `saveRequest` is synchronous, then `res.json(people)` will be executed after `saveRequest` has been executed and completed on each value in the `people` array. If `saveRequest` is asynchronous, then an asynchronous operation will have been started on each value in the `people` array, but it is unlikely all operations will have completed by the time `res.json(people)`. If `saveRequest` is asynchronous, then there is just not enough information provided in the question for us to recommend a way to have `res.json(people)` execute after all operations are complete.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `saveRequest` is asynchronous and returns a promise which is fulfilled with a person, use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(people.map(saveRequest))
  .then(people => res.json(people))
```

Comment: Assuming `saveRequest` is async *AND returns a promise*